# Getting an error when attempting to acces a storyboard resource from code

Tags: windows-phone-8

A developer on my team did some refactoring of a control we're using in WinPhone 8 that represents a card that can be flipped.

We've created two animations using the storyboard named `FrontToBackFlip` and `BackToFrontFlip`, with declarations like: `<Storyboard x:Name="FrontToBackFlip">`

When a `Tap` is received we call

```
this.FrontToBackFlip.Begin()
```

or

```
this.BackToFrontFlip.Begin()
```

The refactoring the code worked before, but now we are getting the following error:

> 'Views.CardCarousel.IssuerCardControl' does not contain a definition for 'FrontToBackFlip' and no extension method 'FrontToBackFlip' accepting a first argument of type 'Views.CardCarousel.IssuerCardControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Note that intellisense can find and complete the references to the Storyboards, so the namespaces and type names seem to be correct in both the XAML and code-behind. It's just that the compiler can't resolve these.

Any suggestions for tracking this down?

Comment: I assume you've tried a Clean and Rebuild? I've seen weird things like this happen with references before so I'll usually try that and even close/re-open Visual Studio. Additionally, did any of the refactoring include any name changes (controls, classes, etc.)? If so, maybe try a search through the solution for the old names just to make sure they aren't still references anywhere.

Comment: lhan16 thanks for the advice. I've done all those things, I've even put the control and all its dependencies in a new winphone project and bam it compiles fine.

Comment: Dang. It sounds like there's something messed up in your project then. If your code is in source control, you could revert the changes, then redo them (one by one, compiling each time), and see if you can narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix the issue by simply adding a new user control to the project, copy and paste the code from the control that was not building.